# Cant create menu in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I created file menu and try to call onCreateOptionsMenu but it doesen't create any menu,here I call my method ,but when I created this activity I see next picture,just input fields without any menu:

[image: (menu) add_item.xml]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the case, in function

> onCreateOptionsMenu()

remove the line

> super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

and make sure that you have not added this for that activity

> android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
> in the androidManifest.xml

and your AppTheme need to look like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" 
    parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

and now  onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) will look like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Hopes this helps